# ROR + Ruby Date Decrease by 15 minutes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, datetime-conversion

If I have `@time = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`,

How can I reduce this time by 15 minutes ?

I already tried this one :: `@reducetime = @time-15.minutes`, works fine at console but give errors while execution. Other than this Is there any way to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you formatting the time before trying to subtract 15 minutes from it? Your `@time` is a string by the time you try to compute `@reducetime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're formatting your time into a string before you're done treating it as a time. This would make more sense:

```
@time       = Time.now
@reducetime = @time - 15.minutes

# And then later when you're reading to display @time...
formatted_time = @time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

You shouldn't format your data until right before you're ready to display it.

If you must have `@time` as the formatted time then you're going to have to parse it before computing `@reducetime`:

```
@reducetime = (DateTime.strptime(@time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") - 15.minutes).to_time
```